# Weight painting cannot be painted

Tags: modeling, armature, weight-painting

I am currently trying to make my model dance, but the eyes aren't following the body.

I tried to paint the eyes red on weight painting thought I can't seem to paint anything at all.

[image]

When I turn to edit mode the body sinks.

[image]

[Blend File](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/vintage-shanghai-fire-station-traffic-signals-ab77fca164fc46eb9ff17bec861724d5)

Comment: you can use any cloud service you like e.g. dropbox and copy the link into your question

Comment: Is it still heavy if you only keep the character + armature and remove all the rest? Maybe the eyes are not part of the body and you need to join them to the body, or keep them separate and parent to the bone you want

Comment: could you please check here?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/q1lun9fyt4vdya2/neko.20230526%20-%20%E3%82%B3%E3%83%94%E3%83%BC.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

For the moment your eyes are not assigned to any vertex group, so they can't be controlled by any bone:

[image]

First thing, bring back your armature to its rest pose:

[image]

Select your object, switch to *Edit* mode and move the eyes where they are supposed to be:

[image]

Check the bone that is supposed to control the eyes, it's probably the one on the second layer called *mixamorig:Head*:

[image]

Assign the eyes to the vertex group called *mixamorig:Head*. At the end don't forget to bring your armature back to *Pose* mode.

[image]

Comment: thank you it worked!